# Can I bind a UserControl to an instance of a class with a converter from className to UserControl-Instance

Tags: wpf, binding, converters

I have asked the same question in a perhaps not so comprehandable way and try again.

In my ModelView I have a lot of classes with two corresponding UserControls for each class. The names of the corresponding UserControls are "ue" + "classname" and "ub" + classname.

In my View I have two ContentControls and use two **Converter** that convert from the original classname (for example CriteriaList) to an instance of the corresponding UserControl (for example ueCriteriaList).

What functions: The shown UserControl is really an instance of the wanted UserControl (for example ueCriteriaList or ubCriteriaList). Which means that the Converter gets the classname of the original class to be shown and creates a functioning instance of the corresponding UserControl.

What doesn't function: The shown UserControl doesn't show the actual content of the instance of the actual class.

Here is my code for the converter:

```
Public Class ueControlConverter
Implements IValueConverter

Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
    Dim aComp As aComponent = value
    Dim AssemblyKlassenname As String = aComp.GetType.ToString
    Dim AssemblyName As String = Left(AssemblyKlassenname, AssemblyKlassenname.IndexOf(".") + 1)
    Dim KlassenName As String = Right(AssemblyKlassenname, AssemblyKlassenname.IndexOf(".") - 1)
    Dim t As Type = Type.GetType(AssemblyName & "ue" & KlassenName)


    Dim o As UserControl = Activator.CreateInstance(t)
    o.DataContext = value

    Return o

End Function

Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
    Return value
End Function

End Class
```

When I stop debugging at "Return o" it says DataContext = "...CriteriaList" with the content of the actual instance. But it is not shown in the actual Window.

The ContentControl Binding:

```
ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=my_aComponent,
                         Converter={StaticResource _ueControlConverter},
                         diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High, 
                         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

My questions:
1. Can I use Converter for binding UserControls to correspending classes using the "correlated" names?

1. What is my mistake?
2. What do I need to do to show the content of the actual class-instance?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: well if you have two `ContentControl`'s where each `ContentControl` only show's the userControl of type `ue` or `ub`, why don't you just use a `DataTemplate` and set the DataTemplate to corresponding `UserControl`. That way your ConentControl can just bind to `my_aComponent` and the DataTemplate will apply the appropriate UserControl based on `ItemTemplate`. As for your current method's issue, not sure but maybe try setting DataContext from the Loaded event like `o.Loaded += (sender,args) => o.DataContext = value;`

Comment: Thank you @Viv. I am new in wpf. With the DataTemplate I have two problems:

Comment: No problem. What are the problem's your having with `DataTemplate`'s?

Comment: @Viv: First I have two usercontrols for each class. How does my ContentControls know which Datatemplate to use? Second: for 50 classes I have to write 100 DataTemplates ... My project is originally a windows forms project and I started to build a small simulation project for testing isolated solutions. Today I realised that perhaps in my simulation the ueUserControl doesn't bind correctly to the class because I changed the class back to not longer inherit from ObservableCollection because of double inheritance in the original project. I test solutions for this in the evening and comment again.

Comment: I would first try to make the not correct binding "public Kriterien as ObservableCollection(of Kriterium)" a Property and try to bind to it again.

Comment: Yes now it shoes the criterialist. It used only a public variable and not a property.

Comment: @Viv: The problem seems to be solved. At least for the moment. Until the next comes. Thanks for the answer. Is there something to do? What is this thing with reputations?

Comment: That's good then. I'm not totally sold if you're applying the concepts of DataTemplate's and `UserControl`'s correctly, It'd be good for you to pick up a beginner's book on WPF and go through a few chapters to get a grasp of how things work in WPF than lead yourself down a rabbit hole(which is very easy with WPF). As for the reputation in SO, check out [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/214404) for an explanation.